# Glassfish 3.1.1 log stops being written to

Tags: logging, glassfish-3

I have somehow broken logging in my Glassfish 3.1.1 deployment.

All I did was attempt to bump up the level of one of the logs, via the "Logger Settings" view under Configurations -> server-config.  I went to the "Log Levels" tab, found "javax.enterprise.system.core.security" and bumped it up from INFO to FINEST, then clicked Save.

From that point on, the last message in the log is "Updated log levels for loggers."  Nothing else ever gets written to the logs anymore!  I can stop, restart the server, but the log never changes.  I decided to go UNDO that change to see if it would fix it, but it did not.  I think there must be some kind of side effect that breaks logging when you try to set the levels via this "Logger Settings" interface.

I reinstalled Glassfish from scratch, and was able to reproduce it again.  Just setting that one value to FINEST breaks logging.

Is this a known issue, and if so, are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found it:  http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-17037